# Sql: Split cell into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

tbl_claims

```
ClaimNo|StatusDate | FromDate
----------------------------------
1076|   2014-02-21 | 2014-02-10
1029|   2014-02-22 | 2014-01-10
```

tbl_settledagainst

```
Claimno |    Amount |   VerificationTeam_ClaimNo
--------------------------------------------------
AC1006    |  1000   |, 1076, 1029
AC1034    |  0.00   |, 1064, 1065, 1066
AC1035    |  0.00   |, 1086
```

The first table is used to store type A claims the second table is used to store type B claims. 
column `tbl_settledagainst.VerificationTeam_ClaimNo` has `tbl_claims.claims` 
ie. **claims 1076, 1029** have been settled agaist **AC1006** (type B) claim. 
Now the problem is that I want to display data in this way:

```
Type_A_claim  | Type_B_Claim |  Amt | StatusDate 
-------------------------------------------------   
 1076         | AC1006       | 1000 | 2014-02-21
 1029         | AC1006       | 1000 | 2014-02-22
```

Thank you in advance.

I have this sql function which I usually use to split string based on delimiter.

**Eg: select * from dbo.split('100,200,abc',',')**

```
**Create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))            
RETURNS @Results TABLE (Items nvarchar(4000))            
AS            
BEGIN            
    DECLARE @INDEX INT            
    DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(4000)            
    -- HAVE TO SET TO 1 SO IT DOESNT EQUAL Z            
    --     ERO FIRST TIME IN LOOP            
    SELECT @INDEX = 1            
    -- following line added 10/06/04 as null            
    --      values cause issues            
    IF @String IS NULL RETURN            
    WHILE @INDEX !=0            


        BEGIN             
         -- GET THE INDEX OF THE FIRST OCCURENCE OF THE SPLIT CHARACTER            
         SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)            
         -- NOW PUSH EVERYTHING TO THE LEFT OF IT INTO THE SLICE VARIABLE            
         IF @INDEX !=0            
          SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)            
         ELSE            
          SELECT @SLICE = @STRING            
         -- PUT THE ITEM INTO THE RESULTS SET            
         INSERT INTO @Results(Items) VALUES(@SLICE)            
         -- CHOP THE ITEM REMOVED OFF THE MAIN STRING            
         SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)            
         -- BREAK OUT IF WE ARE DONE            
         IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK            
    END            

    RETURN            
END**
```

Comment: You should store your data properly in the first place. This question is to find a solution to a problem that ought not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT c.ClaimNo as Type_A_claim, tsa.Claimno  as Type_B_Claim, 
tsa.Amount as Amt, c.StatusDate FROM 
dbo.tbl_settledagainst tsa
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[Split](tsa.VerificationTeam_ClaimNo) fn
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_claims c on c.ClaimNo = fn.Items
```

Comment: SubhanAllah! lol 
I wasnt really expecting someone to actually solve this so easily.  Thanks Bro!

Comment: You're welcome buddy. for every problem there is someone out there who knows the solution

Comment: And please always mark the answer as accepted so the people finding this question will know the correct answer :)